# Python3 import modules from folder to another folder

Tags: python

my structure dictionary is

```
mainFolder    
    folder1
       __init__.py
       file1.py
       file2.py    
    folder2
       __init__.py
       file3.py
       file4.py    
    setup.py    
    __init__.py
```

i need import file4.py from folder2 to folder1/file1.py 

file1.py:

> from ..folder2.file4 import MyClass

and i gets:

> SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative
>   import

how to fix that ?

Comment: setup should be outside your top package, not in it.

Comment: Show how you run the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: @MadPhysicist python3 folder1/file1.py i want run only this file

Comment: `python -m folder1.file1` from the main folder. Or `python -m mainFolder.folder1.file1`, depending on how you really want to structure this thing. You currently have a bit of a mess with the `setup.py`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you must to explicitly name the parent package.
So in your case you need either `from mainFolder.folder2.file4 import Myclass`, either `from folder2.file4 import Myclass`