# Python3 test folder import problems

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to write tests in Python3 with the folder structure

```
package/
    __init.py__
    Foo.py
    Bar.py
test/
    __init.py__
    test_Foo.py
```

Foo.py

```
import Bar
```

test_Foo.py

```
import Foo
```

Running `python3 -m unittest` results in `No module named Foo`

If I changed it to

```
from package import Foo
```

It will resolve, but in `Foo.py` it'll have the error `No module named 'Bar'`

If I change `Foo.py` to

```
from package import Bar
```

The test will run without error, but running `python3 Foo.py` will result in `No module named 'package'`

I've gone through various answers about this kind of problems, like this one

[Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)

and this

[Python3 import modules from folder to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47759739/python3-import-modules-from-folder-to-another-folder)

and none of them address this issue

Answer (score 0):

your project root (and also the **working directory**!) need to be the **parent** of *package*.

Then every `import` will be in the form `import package.module` or `from package import module`.

if you run `python packgae/Foo.py` or `python -m package.Foo` it should work.

Also take a look at [pypa - sample project](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject) to see the recommended Python project structure.

Comment: What makes a folder the project root? There's a parent folder to `package` and `test` but it just includes those two folders.

Comment: a project root is the folder below all your project related exists. it usually has file like setup.py, setup.cfg, requirments.txt and more.
importing inside a project is easy and natural while outside requires installing like 3rd party packages or pythonpath manipulation.